# Retrieve the index of a cross section of a dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say we have a multi-index dataframe `df` like this:

```
|    |    |  one  |  two  
|  A |  B |-------|-------
|----|----|-------|-------
|  x |  p |   1   |   2
|  x |  q |   3   |   4
|  y |  p |   5   |   6
|  y |  q |   7   |   8
```

Now, I can get the index of cross section of the criteria `one > 4` like this:

```
idx = df[df['one'] > 4].index
```

And then, using it with `.ix`:

```
df.ix[idx]
```

yields a slice of the frame:

```
|    |    |  one  |  two  
|  A |  B |-------|-------
|----|----|-------|-------
|  y |  p |   5   |   6
|  y |  q |   7   |   8
```

Now, I want to do the same but with a cross section by one level on the multi-index. The `.xs` is useful in this manner:

```
df.xs('p', level='B')
```

returns:

```
|    |  one  |  two  
|  A |-------|-------
|----|-------|-------
|  x |   1   |   2
|  y |   5   |   6
```

But this dataframe has different index structure and its index is not a slice of the `df` index.

So, my question is, what should to in the place of `idx`, so that the following expression

```
df.ix[idx]
```

to yield

```
|    |    |  one  |  two  
|  A |  B |-------|-------
|----|----|-------|-------
|  x |  p |   1   |   2
|  y |  p |   5   |   6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the argument `drop_level` and set it to `False` to keep the index:

```
In [9]: df.xs('p', level='B', drop_level=False)
Out[9]: 
     one  two
A B          
x p    1    2
y p    5    6
```